# AWK, arith op with odd lines and another arith op with even ones, both print same output

Tags: bash, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how to do an arith op with odd lines and another arith op with even ones, and both arith ops printed in the same output

My first odd attempt was:

```
SUM=100 ; awk -v var1=$SUM '{sum = $1 + var1 ;print $(NR%2==1?sum:0*=0)}' file
```

**INPUT**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**Expected output**

```
101  //100 + 1
4    //2 x 2
103  //100 + 3
16   //4 x 4
```

Thank in advance for any clue or suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v var1=100 '{ value = (NR%2==1) ? $1+var1 : $1*$1; print value } file
```

---

#### Code golfing

The script can be reduced to:

```
awk -v v=100 '{$0=(NR%2)?$1+v:$1^2}1' file
```

I think that's the consensus minimal script (thanks to [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner), [kobame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734304/kobame) and [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for help in producing that — see the comments).  The part in `{...}` does the calculation; the `1` triggers a `print $0` but uses many fewer characters.

Comment: Golf anyone? `awk -v var1=100 '$0=(NR%2)?$1+var1:$1*$1' file`

Comment: I'm not keen on golf, whether the Ryder Cup sort or the code sort.  :D

Comment: @EtanReisner 6 chars shorter: `awk -v v=100 '$0=(NR%2)?$1+v:$1*$1'` :) :) :) /joke - ofc/

Comment: @kobame: Both GNU and BSD `awk` support `5^2` producing 25 (so it isn't xor).  That saves one more byte (`$1^2` vs `$1*$1`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i don't know awk, and in perl the `**2` isn't shorter. You really shortened it! gratz. :)

Comment: @EtanReisner, that will skip even-numbered lines with the value zero.

Comment: @glennjackman: +1, but the problem can be fixed pretty easily.  It needs `{...}1` in golfing style, or `{...;print}` in a more readable style.

Comment: @glennjackman as i already said - i don't know awk - my comment was only an joke because i shortened only the variable `var1` to `v` - not an real golfing...

Comment: @glennjackman, Jonatan Leffer or @kobame, if I am allowed ... I would like to ask what is the use or meaning of numbers at the end of an awk code. i.e.: `{...}1` , are there other numbers with other meanings?

Comment: Scripts for `awk` are made up of pattern:action pairs. The `1` is a pattern; it evaluates to true.  There is no explicit action specified, so the implicit action is `{ print $0 }`.  The code in `{…}` is an action; it has an empty pattern, so it matches every line. So, the golfing script has an empty pattern followed by a non-empty action, followed by a simple pattern and an empty action. Any non-zero number will be equivalent to 1; I expect any non-empty string also counts as equivalent to 1. Only the number 0 (possibly spelled differently, eg `0.0`) and the empty string are false patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Not awk, but perl (for reference only)

```
perl -snE 'say $.%2 ? $_+$s : $_**2' -- -s=100
#or
s=100 perl -nE 'say $.%2 ? $_+$ENV{s} : $_**2'
```

unreadable style ;)

```
perl -snE 'say$.%2?$_+$s:$_**2' -- -s=100
```